# Get instagram image src from Embed with querySelector

Tags: javascript, html, instagram

I have a embed code from instagram, that inserting a photo on my page, then I need to select the image src of this photo with querySelector from my JS-plugin connected to page

But when I try to make selections with JS there are no results after page loaded.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('img');
> HTMLCollection [img.sarafan-pixel]
```

[image: example]
I try

```
document.querySelectorAll('img');
document.getElementsByTagName('img');
```

And there are no images from insta...

But then i goes to Elements in devtools and click on it with selector tool, find this code in DOM and go back to console, there are some results for this img, what a strange behavior?

```
document.getElementsByTagName('img');
> HTMLCollection(5) [img, img.EmbeddedMediaImage, img, img, img]
```

May be there are another ways to get src of instagram photo embedded on page?

Comment: It is likely in an iFrame which is not part of your document. If you inspect it you will see `<iframe... #document`

Comment: Oh yes, noticed, but I can't access to this document from my parent, when i try to select img's inside it `document.getElementById('instagram-embed-0').contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('img')` it show error - `Blocked a frame with origin "http://widget.local" from accessing a cross-origin frame`

Comment: That is a normal security feature - you cannot access cross origin as it clearly states

Comment: Thx, Is there a way to solve this case?